# Django get max date for each month in query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a simple model with the fields `date(DateTimeField)` and `value(IntegerField)`.

I would like the query this model for the value of the last day for each month (see example output)

```
date          value
2020-01-01    55
2020-01-02    12
2020-01-03    13
...
2020-01-31    34
...
2020-02-01    14
2020-02-02    54
2020-02-03    16
...
2020-02-28    23
...
2020-03-01    16
2020-03-02    23
2020-03-03    16
...
2020-03-31    7
```

Desired output:

```
date          value
2020-01-31    34
2020-02-28    23
2020-03-31    7
```

So far, I've managed to to this (but it involves querying the database a lot, so I'd prefer a less database intensive solution)

```
dates = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    month=TruncMonth('date')
).distinct()

for date in dates:
    end_value = MyModel.objects.filter(date__month=date['month'].month).latest('date')
    print(end_value)
```

Comment: maybe loop through 12 months, query filter end_value by that month get the oldest date. You only have to iterate 12 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    #prepare subquery which has max dates per month 
    #and limit resultset only to those dates
    date__in = Subquery(
        MyModel.objects.annotate(
            truncated_to_month = TruncMonth('date') #used to group by truncated to month date
        ).values(
            'truncated_to_month'
        ).annotate(
            max_date_per_month = Max('date') #used to get max date per month i.e. per group
        ).values(
            'max_date_per_month' #only max date per month, so it may be used in __in lookup
        )
    )
).values(
    'date' #group by limited to max date per month
).annotate(
    max_value = Max('value') # and finally select max value per date
).values(
    'date','max_value'
)
```